# Google Polymer create menu tree

Tags: html, menu, tree, repeat, polymer

I want to create menu tree using polymer core-menu. I have table in database:

[image]

table has category with sub category. I want to display it like menu tree. I did something like this:

```
<polymer-element name="category-list" attributes="show">
    <template>
        <style>
        :host {
          display: block;
          width: 100%;
        }
        .cat_item 
        {
            margin: 10px;
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        }
        </style>
        <category-service id="service" categories="{{categories}}"></category-service>

        <core-menu selected="1" selectedindex="1" id="core_menu">
            <template repeat="{{category in categories}}" id="t" if="category.has_child == '1'">
                <core-submenu label="{{category.category_name}}" icon="settings" valueattr="name" class="cat_item">
                    <template ref="t" repeat="{{category in categories}} if="category.parent_id != '0'">
                    </template>
                </core-menu>
            </template>
        </core-menu>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('category-list',
            {
                getParent: function(value)
                {

                }
            }
        );
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

But I cannot using "if", I do something wrong. I need to filter displaying sub item by using database table field. Example:

```
if(category.has_child == '1')
   //display
if(category.parent_id != 0)
   //display
```

I found official example:

```
<template id="myTemplate">
  Used by any template which refers to this one by the ref attribute
</template>

<template bind ref="myTemplate">
  When creating an instance, the content of this template will be ignored,
  and the content of #myTemplate is used instead.
</template>
```

but it not show all what I want. Please help me to solve this task.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your real code then one mistake there is that you haven't enclosed your `if` attribute's value in double-mustache, it should be

```
<template repeat="{{category in categories}}" if="{{category.has_child == '1'}}" id="t">
```

Also, the examples in the [documentation](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#conditional-templates) is

```
if="{{ conditionalValue }}"
```

note taht it says **conditionalValue**, not **expression**. So perhaps try just

```
<template repeat="{{category in categories}}" if="{{category.has_child}}" id="t">
```

and make sure that the value of the `category.has_child` has a vale which is truthy only for those categories which do have childen.

Comment: thanks for your reply but it is not working to me. I think it because I have "1" value in my database field, not "true" or "false"

Answer (score 0):

I created a polymer element to create a menu from JSON. It has some other cool features, and I am going to continue to enhance it. Create a github issue/pull request if you have any issues/ideas

https://github.com/sup3rb0wlz/nb-menu